# nginx not works as expected

Tags: nginx, server

I am a newbie of nginx. And I am recently try to use nginx to serve static content.

below is my nginx configure file:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  server_name localhost;

  location /services {
        root /home/stone/source/javascript/demo/www;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        index index.html;
  }


  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    }

}
```

When user request "http://localhost/index.html", it works as expected and goes to "http://127.0.0.1:3000/index". But when user request "http://localhost/services/demo.html", it should goes to "/home/stone/source/javascript/demo/www/services/demo.html" but it didn't and return me a 404 error. what did I missed ?

Comment: Check your error log and also check the file permissions on every directory to ensure that the nginx user has read access.

Comment: thank you . I figure it out myself. my nginx user don't have permissions to access /home/stone folder.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out myself. My nginx user don't have the rights to access /home/stone folder.
 The owner ship of /home/stone shows as below:

```
drwx------. 59 stone stone  4096 Mar 13 19:40 stone
```

So, the other user can not access stone folder. If I execute this command

```
sudo chmod o+x /home/stone
```

Then everything works as expected!